# Arqade's 2012 Doomsday Edition Secret Santa (DESS)

Tags: discussion

## All the Secret Santa gifts have been sent out! Have a wonderful holiday (whatever you celebrate here)!

## This link should tell you who got what person:

https://docs.google.com/a/buffalo.edu/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0As1tY82SPifOdGpQUGhXX1Roa0xsYTlfT3AySGdUSnc#gid=0

## Assignments have been sent out!

Make sure your steam profile is open to accept messages from anyone.  You will receive a message concerning your Secret Santa #.  There is a GoogleDoc that is open to view that contains your SecretSanta info.

Thanks for participating in this! I'm not very good at organizing, but we're off to a great start. Steam's Winter Sale should hit 12/20/12, which should be perfect for getting gifts for Christmas.

You will have a deadline of 12/23/12 11:59pm to send out your gift(s). Note that I cannot actually assure any gifts will be sent by any person to another person (in case someone else doesn't do it); but you have signed up here which means you have committed yourself to the full thing, and I trust that everyone will get their gifts (regardless of what they get :D)

This should give you a full 4 days to buy your gift for your first Arqade Secret Santa! Have a great Christmas everyone.

Here's the link to your assignments: https://docs.google.com/a/buffalo.edu/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0As1tY82SPifOdHpjTHczTFJyeGVMNmhDRWZFVm5ma2c#gid=0

Note that you will receive your number through Steam, not through GoogleDocs.  I will try messaging you, then sending it through chat. I have saved the results in a seperate doc to ensure consistency. You will receive your number under the user [L!F3] Retrosaur (That is my current Steam profile name)

---

## **Arqade's Secret Santa**

I propose we have a white elephant secret santa gift giving time around Christmas.  The idea is to give each other games on each other's wishlist.

> LessPop_MoreFizz
>
> @Retrosaur EVERYBODY GETS A COPY OF VTM:BLOODLINES!

We've got a bit of ideas floating around. I'll state rules as answers below.  You can feel free to agree or disagree with them, edit them to your own liking, or discuss as you wish.

I'm hoping we can also talk about a price cap.  We've got a couple people who are willing to also donate some games.  Hopefully this'll go as planned and then you can enjoy Christmas with one more game in your steam library!

## **Sign Up Is Closed**

Make sure the community can view your wishlist; you really want those games, right?

Hopefully we can get a list of people willing to buy and receive games, organize them based on wishlist, get a median price thing going on.

Sign up's ended! This'll be a fun Christmas for all of us. I'll set up assignments (random number generators) and assign each user to someone else. If you'd like to join in, but failed to meet the deadline, message me on Steam please.

Sign up has now ended.  The more players/participants/Arqaders we have, the more fun we'll have. Also, join Arqade's Steam Group here: http://steamcommunity.com/groups/arqadecommunity.

The deadline for sending out wishlist gifts will be announced soon.

Ex.

- BlueRaja: (Wishlist: Terraria)
- Spartacus: (Wishlist: GMod)

## **Extra Info**

Taken from BoardGameGeek's [Secret Santa](http://boardgamegeek.com/geekexchange/98):

> 1. First and foremost, Secret Santa is all about the giving. Getting is fun too, but be prepared for the possibility that the person who is sending you a gift may disappoint you. Most people do a good job, but there are always going to be a handful of unfortunate situations that come up.
>
>    If you sign up for Secret Santa treat it as a responsibility and make it a priority. Those who sign-up but don't send gifts <s>will face the possibility of account privileges being suspended as a result.</s> *[Sorry, we can't suspend users just for being awful human beings and failing forever at a Secret Santa. --bp]*
> 2. You have until **DECEMBER 18th** to sign up. If you have second thoughts after signing up, you also have until that deadline to delete your registration.
> 3. Keep your wishlist (NOT want list) of games updated. The expectation is that your Santa will send a new game from your wishlist. Please have at least twenty currently available games on your list, and try to have most of them fall within a reasonable price range. If you have a small, expensive, or difficult-to-fulfill wishlist then don't be surprised if you get something that isn't on your list. The more you have on your list the easier it is for your Secret Santa to find something for you.

Comment: I think you're going to need to add in a bit more explanation in order to not confuse everybody here.

Comment: You want to give people games that won't be played?

Comment: @RavenDreamer: What secret santa gift is ever used to begin with?

Comment: I've got 4 copies of dota2 to give away :p

Comment: we could also just get rid of the white elephant part and make it a secret santa thing

Comment: if anyone's willing to play [this game](http://store.steampowered.com/app/27400/) I'll personally buy them a copy.

Comment: I support this idea, but surely we should be able to donate any game we want (not just rarely played ones). Maybe we could incentivise bigger donations by having price brackets?

Comment: @spartacus I see your [Dangerous High School Girls in Trouble!](http://store.steampowered.com/app/27400/) and raise with my [Secret of the Magic Crystals](http://store.steampowered.com/app/45100/)

Comment: Just for the record, VTM:Bloodlines is a diamond of a game. A diamond in the rough, but one still.

Comment: @kotekzot agreed, though if anyone does play it, the unofficial patch is an absolute must

Comment: You know, we could get technical, draw a Steam ID from a (hat) and see what's on their wish list.  Set a price cap if necessary.  Only issue is direct gifting would basically rule out any sort of secret.

Comment: Creating a middleman account, entrusting someone here to access it, then having that account send games to the user, all the while hiding identity of real user.

Comment: @Retrosaur with all DLC.

Comment: @spartacus - It actually has neat art direction and an 81 Metacritic, I'm not exactly scared.  Hell, I may buy this for myself now...

Comment: @Retrosaur Now don't get me wrong, but isn't the secret santa part just where you don't know who you are getting your present from? But at the time when it is handed out you kinda do?

Comment: I think so, not sure though.  It varies by location

Comment: As an active steam trader, I'd be willing to donate a game or two for this.  You should explicitly state that it's steam-tradable games only; otherwise you will have 1000 entries of unwanted Indiegala games.  You should also disallow DLCs, betas (such as Dota 2 or Airmech) and The Ship, which are so abundant they are basically worthless.

Comment: @spartacus I've got [.9 hours logged](http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197970257956/games?tab=all) on that game! It's not bad in the ways you'd think. It's bad in completely different ways.

Comment: @DannyPflughoeft - I'd love to know where all these copies of The Ship are coming from, because I've always wanted to try it but not enough to pay for it and I've never managed to pick up a promo.

Comment: @Shinrai if you buy a copy, you get two gift copies. When those gift copies are redeemed, each redeemer gets one gift copy of their own. The publisher also recently had a $5 promotion -- so that's 5 copies for $5.

Comment: @Shinrai also there has been recently a charity promotion in which they were giving away free copies of the game -- so that's 5 copies for 0$

Comment: @Shinrai: In addition to what YVes said *(everyone who buys it gets 2 free copies)*, and what Kappei said *(about two weeks ago, they did a "raffle" which basically gave everyone with an email address two free steam-tradable copies... which a lot of the less-ethical traders exploited to get dozens of copies)*, in last year's Winter Event *(free games for getting achievements)* they  gave out 100k copies, the most of any game for that promotion.  I still have a few extra copies from that event; if you'd like one, just message me on steam *(I'm in the Arqade steam group)* and you can have one.

Comment: @Kappei Then you should give upvotes to my questions (and answers since I am the only one playing this game). http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/secret-of-magic-crystals

Comment: This sounds like it would result in a lot of people getting games they already have.  Based on the giveaway from last year, most people's extras are the same.  Partly because the Humble Bundle keeps putting the same stupid games in every other pack....

Comment: Aw, I missed the sign up for this, I missed the sign up for the reddit SS, and my office isn't doing one D:

Comment: Don't worry about it, this is only in the planning stages.  Nothing is concrete yet, and we have nothing down yet.

Comment: What do you mean by "leave a reply"? Is it a comment in the question, a comment in the answer, or another answer? Is everyone who's ever commented in the question considered to be in whether they want to or not?

Comment: Is steams list of sent gifts public? I.e. do we know if someone who said they'd send something will? Or is each person getting assigned someone so the receiving party can confirm it?

Comment: I highly suggest setting up a Google Form or Spreadsheet to allow people to sign up.

Comment: sign me up (12 chars)

Comment: @kotsu: Same, I'm interested, but don't see anyone else (apart from spartacus signing up)

Comment: Sign me up aswell

Comment: Well, I'm in, I really think this should be a Google doc or something though.

Comment: Alright, added the sign up sheet under Arqade's Little Helpers

Comment: @Retrosaur The spreadsheet is set to view only.

Comment: @Kotsu: I think I've managed to add my name (changes saved to drive it said), although maybe that's just my copy.

Comment: Everyone who wants to do this also remember to join the steam group: http://steamcommunity.com/groups/arqadecommunity

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Looks like its fixed. Thanks Retrosaur!

Comment: I've joined the Steam group but have never used Google docs before so I will attempt that with some trepidition.

Comment: @Lyrion: FYI there's now a google docs signup plage (check the orignal edited post).

Comment: Alright I'm looking to finalize the list by the 15th.  If possible, sign up as soon as possible.  Also, please join the Steam group Arqade to make finding your profiles easier. I'll set up a private database linking participants with random particpants.   This should be exciting!

Comment: Sorry if this is messy, this is my first time setting up something this big.  Hopefully this'll become a fun experience for everyone.

Comment: I've changed the deadline to December 18th to hopefully draw in more people

Comment: Also, ENSURE YOUR PROFILE IS PUBLIC / WE CAN SEE YOUR WISHLIST. I think I found one that was private when I checked a day or so ago.

Comment: @Retrosaur: Not sure why but when I follow your steam id link I get an error page. "The specified profile could not be found."

Comment: @MBraedley: Your steam account is private, we can't see your wish list.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: My profile is set to users only.  Make sure you're logged in.

Comment: @MBraedley: Ahh ok, cool. Didn't realise you could do that.

Comment: Alright, set to users only as well.

Comment: Today's the final day.  We only have 6 people, but that doesn't mean it can't...be fun :D

Comment: @Retrosaur I count 8 :p

Comment: Sign up's ended!  This'll be a fun Christmas for all of us.  I'll set up assignments (random number generators) and assign each user to someone else.  If you'd like to join in, but failed to meet the deadline, message me on Steam please.

Comment: @Retrosaur I think there may be some people who are participating but aren't signed up on the Google sheet.

Comment: @Shinrai Message Retrosaur if you're participating.

Comment: @AliceRees Message Retrosaur if you're participating.

Comment: @Kotsu - You're right, I never saw that go up.

Comment: @Retrosaur - I never saw the Google doc go up, I'm totally in.  I'll Steam message you tonight when I get home if this doesn't catch you.

Comment: @Retrosaur I'd like to still be in if possible, sorry I derped and missed the sign up

Comment: I've cheekily signed onto the Google doc :P Just boot me off if I can't join in.

Comment: No worries, I'm still doing assignments for people. honestly though, it'll be a bigger challenge to do this as a "secret".  Also, since Steam's Winter Sale hasn't hit yet, I really wish it would, because that would open up all sorts of buying options.

Comment: I don't suppose there's a way to send people gifts on steam without adding them as a friend?

Comment: Oh, you got it! Uh...you'll have to add them as a friend.  I didn't factor this in when I started everything. Next  year'll be different, I promise.

Comment: @AliceRees: I've asked a question on arqade, but it doesn't look like it, unless you have their email address.

Comment: @Retrosaur On the document it sais my profile is private... but it isn't? I'm at work atm, not logged into steam and i can still see my wishlist

Comment: My bad.  I couldn't comment on your profile, so I could not send you your assignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## **Rules:**

- Steam tradable games only.
- NO DLCs
- NO betas

Any game is fine as long as it follows the rule mentioned above.
Please try to gift games that are on the user's wishlist.  However, as mentioned above, if the price is too absurd or the list is too shallow, feel free to gift something else within your own budget restrictions.

You will have by 12/23/12 11:59 pm to send out your gifts (in time for Christmas, Kwanza, any other holiday). That's all, and thanks for participating.

Refer to this link to link your number for your Secret Santa:
https://docs.google.com/a/buffalo.edu/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0As1tY82SPifOdHpjTHczTFJyeGVMNmhDRWZFVm5ma2c#gid=0

Let me know if you have any questions pertaining to the event itself, your own number, or anything else as comments underneath this answer.

Comment: I wouldn't exactly say price cap, as prices are different in alot of different countries. I would say pick a game and the price of that game is the max price?

Comment: What game would we use though?

Comment: I fail to see why there should be a price cap, if somebody really feels like being generous.  The expectation should not be that if you buy a new AAA release that you're likely to get one yourself in return, but if you want to do that for someone...

Comment: I agree that a price cap isn't necessary, but a guideline for minimum price should be given.  Boardgamegeek.com runs a really well coordinated secret santa.  You can see their guidelines at http://boardgamegeek.com/geekexchange/98.  I think we should allow non-tradable games that are on the user's wishlist.

Comment: I still say you need to know who you are giving a game too, just so you can look at their wishlist to see what you want to give. And a minimum price is good aswell, but i still think you should take in mind that if you say for example minimum 50$ thats 38 euro's. Thats not the same price range....

Comment: @Lyrion - I am sure if there was a minimum price at all it would be something more like $3 than $50 - a price that high would exclude a lot of people, never mind the issue of differing rates in different countries.

Comment: @Shinrai I was just saying as an example, doesn't need to be 50$. But if you want to buy something of peoples wishlist I don't think there will be alot of 3$ games on there.