# Gauging community's interest in a Secret Santa 2013

Tags: discussion, community-event

When I first joined Arqade, I think one of the first thing's I tried to setup was a intra-site [Secret Santa](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5536/arqades-2012-doomsday-edition-secret-santa-dess).

We did not have many participants, but there were enough to actually have a rather fun Secret Santa. Hopefully, at least, I believe all parties involved had a pretty fun time.

That said, I'm thinking about doing the same thing on Steam again this year.

I'd just like to gauge the community's interest and see what the consensus is on this. Would more people be willing to sign up? (last year we had 10-ish participants).

Please let me know in the comments or in answer if you can participate.  Nothing's concrete yet, but I do plan on making one (if I have enough support) for this year!

EDIT1:
Looks like we have a stronger "pre-order" list this time around.  As such, I'll be using this question to have people post their opinions on rules, limitations on game (please, no copies of The Ship), etc.  Please post any comments, concerns, or questions in either comments or as an answer, thanks!

Comment: Do you mean exchanging Steam gifts?

Comment: Yup! Basically, making a Not So Secret Secret Santa on Steam

Comment: Wouldn't this be more of a white elephant exchange? Either way, I'm down.

Comment: Not necessarily, at least from what I could tell, most of the users in last year's Secret Santa traded out good stuff they already had or bought something during the winter sale and gifted it out.

Comment: Sounds like fun.

Comment: I would like to participate.

Comment: retrosaur, I see that you haven't even installed (much less played) my gift to you yet, I don't see dangerous high school girls in trouble on your game list ;)  I can forgive you on that part, but not installing Shogun 2 either is a travesty.

Comment: @spartacus What is this DHSGIT you speak of? Surely it can't be....oh no....OH WAIT

Comment: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7634/arqades-2013-somewhat-secret-but-not-so-secret-secret-santa

Comment: Why not just delete this now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**I think we should do this again this year.**

This was a nice way to celebrate Christmas time with the community last year, small as the participation was :) It's also not an especially complicated thing to set up and Steam makes it so easy. Let's do it!

Comment: Yep, I'd be down for it

Comment: If you're down for it, I'm up for it.

Comment: The only annoying thing was as a European waiting for an American to come online :p

Comment: I'm interested as well

Comment: Seems like we've got quite a bit of support here, as such, I've proceeded to make a new page exclusively for the SEcret Santa itself.

Comment: Sounds great, I love this sort of thing.